# Handling session params in pipelets in Intershop 7

Tags: intershop

I have noticed that in Intershop7 a configuration value is added in pipelet xml which allows to flag certain parameters as "session" parameters:

[image]

By the description, I would assume by enabling this flag pipelet execute method would provide a mean of storing this value in session dictionary. However, I cannot find a description anywhere on the support site of how we should handle the session dictionary within pipelet for "session parameters". Is there a way to do that or it's still recommended to use "ExchangeSessionObject" pipelet for storing objects into session dictionary?

Comment: Hi Renato,
your assumption is right, the option 'Session' means, that the value is read or written from/into the session instead the pipeline dictionary. To interact with the session you need to get the requests session (e.g. com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.request.Request.getCurrent().getSession()).
If you want to store a value in the session from within a pipeline you can and should use ExchangeSessionObject.

Comment: @Stefan I'm not quite sure I understand what the "session" flag in the pipelet configuration actually does. Whether I check it or not, I can still handle the session objects from within the pipelet, there is no need to add parameter values in pipelet configuration (that actually generates warnings in pipelet XML)